# i need one accomadation entity

Tags: spring-boot

I need a Accommodation entity in that i have location column when i click here it display many location if i select one location then in this entity only i have column "save-dates" that stores multiple dates and "timeslotAvailable" columns also i need to store multiple timeslot like "hh-mm-ss to hh-mm-ss"....i have tried some code pl;z check it..

this is Accommodation Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="accommadation")
public class Accommadation {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="AccmdtnId")
private long AccmdtnId;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name="saveDates")
private Date saveDates;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name="available_Dates")
private Date availableDates;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm:ss")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "hh-mm-ss")
@Column(name="time_Slot_Available")
private Time  timeSlotAvailable;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy="accdtn",targetEntity=Location.class,cascade = 
CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Location> locations=new ArrayList<Location>();
```

this is Location entity**

```
@Entity
public class Location {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="location_Id")
private long locationId;

@Column(name="location")
private String location;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY  
,targetEntity=Accommadation.class)
@JoinColumn(name="AccmdtnId")
private Accommodation accdtn;
```

here i have taken separate entities but it is  needed or not and i have posted data i got output like this below location table getting 2 times why

{

```
"saveDates": "2019-02-02",
"availableDates": "2019-02-25",
"timeSlotAvailable": "02:00:00",
"locations": [
    {
        "locationId": 3,
        "location": "banglore"
    },
    {
        "locationId": 4,
        "location": "ubbali"
    }
],
"accmdtnId": 2,
"loactions": [
    {
        "locationId": 3,
        "location": "banglore"
    },
    {
        "locationId": 4,
        "location": "ubbali"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Try to isolate your problem more, this is way to much code for us to read. What exactly are coursing you issues?

Comment: in controller how @GetMapping  code works in DAO i have criteria interface how this is works

Answer (score 0):

As you control comes to backend controller. Using `@requestMapping` it'll decide particular method to execute. Once you get into that method it'll find the service which you called from the method. From service, you must have communicated with DAO for data stimulation. As your control goes from service to DAO. DAO will fire the query for you which will use your coding of connection URL in your `application.properties` file. If you want to understand further you can ask your query specifically here again.